# I can't get the code to work on my hosting

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have an error that when I run the code on localhost, it still works normally, but after putting the code on the hosting, I get an error like this

[image]

Comment: The error gives you the page and line number of the error. Look at your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.